# XML and threads

Tags: xml, delphi

Hi 
Within my application I save certain information in xml external
file on disc. I wanted to access and just read this file from other threads 
and application or services as well simultaneously.

For instance I would like to modify the files (not very often) from the main
vcl thread and just reading them from other threads, application and services.

Should I user critical section? I am thinking to aquire critical section modify
some values or adding xml nodes from main vcl thread and when done signal threads 
that files have been modifed so they should reload them.

Any suggestion? I use delphi 2009 win32.

Answer (score 3):

For your particular case the best is [Multiple Read Exclusive Write Synchronizer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer)

Note that both `critical section` and `Multiple Read Exclusive Write Synchronizer` can be used only within a single process - you can't use them to synchronize an access to a shared resource from two or more processes (applications).

Comment: +1, with the mention: use a single instance of the XML document and access that from all threads. The TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer assures that multiple reads can happen at the same time, only writes block; Using a single XML document assures that all threads access fresh data.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion: do nothing special!

Lets think about the possible cases:

1. The worker thread read the file while no one else is using it -> no problem
2. The worker thread reads the file and get an error because e.g. someone is using the file exclusive -> you have always to handle this case (e.g. Sleep and try again after a while)

Just handle this as you are implementing to independent programs for reading and writing. The only difference is that it is easy to signal the worker thread that someone (main thread) changed the content of the file. The critical section is implemented by the file system ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mutex object when writing, and other threads can read if only the mutex object doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using windows file locking. Initially I would start by making each thread use the correct flags when trying to access the file - flags that only read use that flag, and the writing flag uses write-deny-read. Since reading the file should be fast that should work fine - the writing thread will need to retry on access denied, but that should be fairly rare. That depends a lot on how often reading happens. From your description it should not be a problem.

If the writing thread does block too much because of the reading threads you could try write-allow-read locking and see whether that works. It might. If it doesn't, try truncating the file as the first step when you write. So, open the file, set length to zero and flush, then build the new file in memory before writing it in one go (MemoryStream.SaveToFile then Flush or Close).